# UserProfile not creating in custom model using User model as OneToOneField(User)

Tags: python, django, model, superuser, django-auth-models

I am creating the super user through admin panel or command line, but it is not showing in the custom model in the database.

models.py

```js
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Using OneToOnefield should create the user in the Profile model automatically but it is not happening. I am not sure what is wrong because in the previous project it was workiing fine. Also I have registered the models in admin.py.

Comment: A `OneToOneField` does *not* automatically create another model object.

Comment: But in other projects it was dealing on its own.

Comment: likely that was due to the use of signals.

Comment: I was using command line for creating super user so I didn't use signals.

Comment: the `createsuperuser` command also triggers signals... The idea is that if you create a user, through whatever means, it will normally trigger the signals, unless you do bulk creates/updates/deletes... But that will not happen by creating a user through the command line.